# Dataset Query with condition on two subsequent rows

Tags: dataset, query

The following `Dataset`

```
ds = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "Type"} -> #] &]@
{{"C09",SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 2, 21, 50, 0.}], "D"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 4, 24, 20, 35, 0.}], "T"}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], "T"}, {"C09", 
SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}], "V"}, {"C09", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}], "D"}, {"C09", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 8, 19, 40, 0.}], "T"}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 12, 0, 2, 0.}], "V"}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], "T"}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 24, 19, 45, 0.}], "D"}, {"C10", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 6, 1, 17, 0, 0.}], "T"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0.}], "V"}, {"C09", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], "T"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 23, 20, 50, 0.}], "T"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 25, 21, 0, 0.}], "D"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 5, 4, 22, 0, 0.}], "V"}, {"C11", 
SQLDateTime[{2013, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}], "T"}}
```

looks after `ds[SortBy[{#"ID" &, #"Date" &}]]` like this
[image]

My question is now, how can I extract two subsequent lines with the same `ID`, both having `Type T`?

As it only occurs in the 2nd and 3rd row of `ID C10`. All other cases, with a `D` or `V` in between are not interesting for me (e.g. last three lines).

I assume one has to use the `Query` functionality, but since I'm still at the beginning of my Mathematica studies, I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ds[SortBy[{#"ID" &, #"Date" &}]][SplitBy[#, {#ID, #Type} &] &][Select[Length[#] == 2 &]]
```

> ```
> {{<|"ID" -> "C10", "Date" -> SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], "Type" -> "T"|>, 
>  <|"ID" -> "C10", "Date" -> SQLDateTime[{2013, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], "Type" -> "T"|>}}
> ```

EDIT

Added `Select` after WReach, though I don't believe it should only return the `First` instance.

Comment: +1 You could also replace `7` with `SelectFirst[Length@# >= 2 &]` to address it structurally.

Comment: @alancalvitti Sorry for the late reply, I was in vacation. Any idea how to re-establish the nice formating of a `Dataset` for the result?

Comment: `Flatten[ds[SortBy[{#"ID" &, #"Date" &}]][SplitBy[#, {#ID, #Type} &] &][Select[Length[#] >= 2 &]]]` helps to get back a usable `Dataset`